# Delete Rows in table if condition is true

Tags: sql-server

Aim: Using a Query - Delete all customers with no Assets

I have 2 tables. I want to delete all the rows where my count = 0:

**My condition**

```
if (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Asset_Table WHERE Customer_ID='myString' ==0){
   Delete row from Account_table 
}
```

**Accounts_Table :**

```
CustomerID       |    Customer_Name  |   Onwner 
-------------------------------------------------------------
 123             |           Jake     |     someowner1
 124             |           Ralph    |     someowner2
 ...             |            ....    |      ....
```

**Asset_Table:**

```
AssetINDEX     | Customer_ID |  Serial_ID |
-------------------------------------------------
    5564       |     123     |  xyz    
    5565       |     128     |  xyz1
    ....       |    ...      |  xyz2
```

**Expected Result**

Accounts_Table :

```
CustomerID       |    Customer_Name  |   Onwner 
-------------------------------------------------------------
 123             |           Jake     |     someowner1
 ...             |            ....    |      ....
```

Asset_Table:

```
AssetINDEX     | Customer_ID |  Serial_ID |
-------------------------------------------------
    5564       |     123     |  xyz    
    ....       |    ...      |  xyz2
```

Comment: `Customer_ID='myString'`  id is a string? and after you add `= 0` this should fail, no?

Comment: `Delete` + `inner join`

Comment: Why delete `Customer_Id` 123 when it has `AssetIndex` 5564 assigned to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears in the "results" you gave in your question that you would like the data to be cleaned both ways. So that the only records remaining have references in both tables.  To do this you need two statements and you can use the EXISTS clause.

```
DELETE FROM Accounts_Table 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT CustomerID FROM Asset_Table WHERE Accounts_Table.CustomerID 
= Asset_Table.Customer_ID)

DELETE FROM Asset_Table 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT AssetINDEX FROM Accounts_Table where Asset_Table.Customer_ID 
= Accounts_Table.CustomerID)
```

Comment: Very true, this cleaned up my Asset_table

Answer (score 1):

> Delete all customers with no Assets

You can use `exists` to verify not existing rows in **Asset_Table**:

```
delete from Account_table AT
 where not exists (select AssetINDEX from Asset_Table 
                    where Customer_ID = AT.CustomerID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query should work;

```
delete from Accounts_Table where CustomerID not in (select Customer_ID from Asset_Table )
```

Comment: Using an IN clause may be very slow if this is a large dataset

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE C FROM
    Account_table AS C
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            'the customer does not have any asset'
        FROM
            Asset_Table AS A
        WHERE
            A.Customer_ID = C.Customer_ID)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made (table definitions, etc).